# Use FPDF in Controller

Tags: controller, php-7, fpdf

I'm using a website made only in PHP (no Framework).
I 've created a button to allow user to download data in PDF. When he press button it will create a PDF and startinf downloading PDF.

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <div class="input_field">
        <input type="submit" value="Get Data" class="btn waves-effect waves-light myBlue" name="get_data">
    </div>
</form>
```

the request is sent to a Controller :

```
<?php

$user = checkConnected($bdd)
checkAutorisation($user, true); 



if (!isset($_POST['get_data'])) {

    $pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World !', 1);
    $pdf->Output();
}

require('views/Head.php');
require $_dir["front"] . "file.php";
```

But when I'm going to the page, I have an error 500 can't find FODF class.
How can I fix it ?
I've try of course with :

```
use Fpdf\Fpdf;
```

it changes nothing, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soluce found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339810/using-fpdf-library), just have to say :

```
use \FPDF;
```